# GIMP Python-fu exporting file only exports transparent layer

Tags: scripting, gimp, save-image, python-fu

I am having issues saving images in python via GIMP. I can get the image and apply the effects I want, but when I go to save, it only saves one layer and not everything (NOTE: The background is transparent) and because the background is transparent, I cannot get it to save anything besides the transparent background. The code I am using is posted below:

```
image_array = gimp.image_list()
i=0
for image in image_array:
    img = image_array[i]
    layers = img.layers
    last_layer = len(layers)-1
    try:
        disable=pdb.gimp_image_undo_disable(img)
        pdb.gimp_layer_add_alpha(layers[0])
        drw = pdb.gimp_image_active_drawable(img)
        pdb.plug_in_colortoalpha(img,drw,(0,0,0))
        drw = pdb.gimp_image_active_drawable(img)
        enable = pdb.gimp_image_undo_enable(img)

    except:
        print "ERROR"

    pdb.file_png_save(img, drw, "C:\\Users\\jammer\\Desktop\\test.png",
                      "test.png",0,9,1,1,1,1,1)
    i+=1
```

I have also tried `file_png_save2`, but I have a feeling the problem lies in the drw object as I just want to replicate the option of clicking **File->Export** and saving as PNG without doing that via GUI. I would rather have it save automatically (I have 49 images and each will be named automatically, but first I need to get it to export correctly with one image). as I said before, the code above only exports a transparent background, even changing to a GIF does not resolve the issue. How do I export a file as a PNG while keeping all layers and transparent background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my problem! I was not merging the visible layers and setting that equal to the new layer, which I then used as the "drawable object" when saving the image as a png! I have posted the fixed code below:

```
image_array = gimp.image_list()
i=0
for image in image_array:
    img = image_array[i]
    layers = img.layers
    last_layer = len(layers)-1
    try:
        disable=pdb.gimp_image_undo_disable(img)
        pdb.gimp_layer_add_alpha(layers[0])
        drw = pdb.gimp_image_active_drawable(img)
        pdb.plug_in_colortoalpha(img,drw,(0,0,0))
        layer = pdb.gimp_image_merge_visible_layers(img, gimpfu.CLIP_TO_IMAGE)#FIXES PROBLEM OF ONLY EXPORTING TRANSPARENCY!
        enable = pdb.gimp_image_undo_enable(img)

    except:
        print "ERROR"

    pdb.file_png_save2(img, layer, "C:\\Users\\jammer\\Desktop\\test.png","test.png",1,9,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Merging all layers is the way to do it - but you only want that in cases, like in yours, where the Image is "disposable" - After merging the layers there is no going back (there is no call to "undo" in GIMP). The usual approach is to call `pdb.gimp_image_duplicate`, and perform the  layer merging in the duplicate.