# How do I save (export) all layers with gimp's script fu?

Tags: python, gimp, python-fu

With gimp fu, I can save the content of *one* layer (at least, that is how I interprete the definition of `gimp_file_save` because it takes the parameter `drawable`).

Now, I have the following script:

```
from gimpfu import *

def write_text():

    width  = 400
    height = 100

    img = gimp.Image(width, height, RGB)
    img.disable_undo()


    gimp.set_foreground( (255, 100, 20) )
    gimp.set_background( (  0,  15, 40) )

    background_layer = gimp.Layer(
                           img,
                           'Background',
                           width,
                           height,
                           RGB_IMAGE,
                           100,
                           NORMAL_MODE)

    img.add_layer(background_layer, 0)
    background_layer.fill(BACKGROUND_FILL)

    text_layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(
                    img,
                    None,
                    60,
                    40,
                    'Here is some text',
                    0,
                    True,
                    30,
                    PIXELS,
                    'Courier New'
                )

    drawable = pdb.gimp_image_active_drawable(img)

#   Either export text layer ...
#   pdb.gimp_file_save(img, drawable, '/temp/tq84_write_text.png', '?')

#   .... or background layer:
    pdb.gimp_file_save(img, background_layer, '/temp/tq84_write_text.png', '?')

register(
  proc_name     = 'tq84_write_text',
  blurb         = 'tq84_write_text',
  help          = 'Create some text',
  author        = 'Rene Nyffenegger',
  copyright     = 'Rene Nyffenegger',
  date          = '2014',
  label         = '<Toolbox>/Xtns/Languages/Python-Fu/_TQ84/_Text',
  imagetypes    = '',
  params        = [],
  results       = [],
  function      = write_text
)

main()
```

When I use `pdb.gimp_file_save(img, drawable, '/temp/tq84_write_text.png', '?')` to save the image, It will only export the "text" layer. Yet, If I use `pdb.gimp_file_save(img, background_layer, '/temp/tq84_write_text.png', '?')` it will only export the background. So, how can I export both layers into one image (as the menu `File -> Export As` would do).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482280/gimp-python-fu-exporting-file-only-exports-transparent-layer ?

Answer (score 19):

What is done internally, even by GIMP file-exporter plug-ins for all formats is: duplicate the image, merge all visible layers, them save the resulting drawable.

This is easier, and take less resources than it sounds. Effectively you just have to replace your save line

```
pdb.gimp_file_save(img, background_layer, '/temp/tq84_write_text.png', '?')
```

by

```
new_image = pdb.gimp_image_duplicate(img)
layer = pdb.gimp_image_merge_visible_layers(new_image, CLIP_TO_IMAGE)
pdb.gimp_file_save(new_img, layer, '/temp/tq84_write_text.png', '?')
pdb.gimp_image_delete(new_image)
```

(The last call just "deletes" the new image from program memory, freeing up the resources, of course)

Answer (score 4):

I have found out that if you pass `None` as the `drawable` argument to `gimp_xcf_save()`, GIMP (at least version 2.8) will save all layers of the image to the XCF file:

`pdb.gimp_xcf_save(0, image, None, 'file.xcf', 'file.xcf')`

Comment: In 2.10 (the jpeg version), I get "Calling error for procedure 'gimp-drawable-type':
Procedure 'gimp-drawable-type' has been called with an invalid ID for argument 'drawable'. Most likely a plug-in is trying to work on a layer that doesn't exist any longer."

Answer (score 1):

What I found easiest was to flatten the image then just save using the first layer:

```
img.flatten()
pdb.gimp_file_save(img, img.layers[0], 'image.jpg', '?')
```